# Having more than one entity context

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Let's say I've extended identity framework `dbContext` to build my own, and I've our authenticated controller who get injected with the `dbContext` and fetch an entity related with the current `ApplicationUser`, entity framework will relate the two entities leading to a server error because of circular references.

We don't want to serialize circular references.

So we create a new `dbContext` in the method who istantiate a new `dbcontext` and query the unrelated entities, this will work. But **this is not testable**, we don't want our controller to strictly depends on the `dbContext`, we want it to be injected.

So we add a second parameter, in the constructor, unfortunately this will make the system **inject the same `dbContext` twice**, not so useful.

We tried to create a class `fakeDbContext` who inherit from `dbContext` and add it services and use it, **but now we got two dbcontext**, who can potentially generate migrations and configurations and errors...

Which is the right way of doing this in the new MVC6 ?

### Edit...

I found out that if my controller require an `IEnumerable<dbContext>` i get all the object registered as service of that type, so just doubling the part in *startup.cs* where we add the `dbContext` in the service registration area i get two of them...

The drawback here is that i don't know wich one is the *virgin* one, it looks like it goes in order of registration, but i have no clue, if this will change.

### Edit 2 ...

I've created a `TransientDbService` class who have just a factory method taking the `IserviceProvider`, it use it to get the options to construct the `dbContext`, and then expose it. I've registered it as transient, then in the controller i require this service type.

the drawback here is if i'll ever need a third `dbContext` i should write more code, more code means errors and maintaning it.

### Edit 3 ...

Not having two dbContext at all. The following setting allow me to have no relationships valorized.

```
Database.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = Microsoft.Data.Entity.QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
```

The drawback here is that i can't use my model graph, making everything more complex...

### Edit 4 ...

https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/issues/352

Comment: While trying to summarize what I have already responded in GitHub I realized that I haven't asked you more details about the circular reference. Maybe there are other ways to avoid that.

Comment: Well avoiding circular references in queries I did in that method is easy the problem was finding out I got an user connected to the post I queried because that user is the logged one and also the creator of the post,  maybe identity framework should use AsNoTracking() or I found a bug

Comment: Also creating a new post gave me some troubles,  after I added the entity with my userId only and did a SaveChanges I suddenly got the user related,  and next step was to return it so I got a circular reference there too

Comment: P. P. S.  Another way of avoiding that is surely copy to new objects or dtos but I kinda dislike that if it is not really necessary...  Maybe it's only me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right to think that no tracking queries will help in some cases, but other times you'll need to have more than one instance of the DbContext created.

You normally use the `AddDbContext<TContext>()` method in startup to make sure an instance of your context type is created per request and the right `DbContextOptions` and service provider get set on it. When you need to deviate from this pattern you have a few options, e.g.:

1. Include a constructor in your derived DbContext class that takes an `IServiceProvider` and passes it to the base constructor. Make sure your controller takes `IServiceProvider`. Once you do this you should be able to create `DbContext` manually with something like this:

   `using(var context1 = new MyDbContext(serviceProvider),
         var context2 = new MyDbContext(serviceProvider))
   {  ...`
2. To avoid having to change the constructor signatures on your derived `DbContext` type you can take advantage of the `DbContextActivator` class (it is our Internal namespace), e.g.:

   `using(var context1 = DbContextActivator.CreateInstance<MyDbContext>(serviceProvider),
         var context2 = DbContextActivator.CreateInstance<MyDbContext>(serviceProvider)
   {...`

Note: If you are still using `AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => ...)` in startup it should pull those options automatically from the service provider. But you can also choose to either include the `DbContextOptions` as a parameter in the constructor or override the `OnConfiguring()` method for that.

I am giving you examples that create two separate `DbContexts` in a using block, but you should also be able to mix those with the regular "per-request" DbContext you would get injected in the controller's constructor.

Besides these options currently available I have created a new issue to track other possible improvements on how to create multiple instance of the same `DbContext` type in the same request:

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4441